# image on top of image css

Tags: css, image

I have designed a site.
as you can see the learnmore image isnt getting on top of the slideshow images.

u have the following php code

```
<?php
$directory = 'uploads'; 
 $learnmore_img_path='learnmore';
echo'<div style="position: relative; ">';
 try {    
// Styling for images

 echo "<div id=\"myslides\" style='position: relative; z-index:99999;'>";

foreach ( new DirectoryIterator("../" . $directory) as $item )       {          
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        $path = "/" . $directory . "/" . $item;


        echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" width=861 height=443  href='#' style='position: relative;'/>";

            $learnmore_img_path='learnmore';
        $path1="/" . $learnmore_img_path . "/" . 'learnmore.jpg';       


    }       
}
 echo "</div>";
    $path1="/" . $learnmore_img_path . "/" . 'learnmore.jpg';   

  echo '<a href="#" id="examplelink">';
  echo "<img src=\"" . $path1 . "\" width=160 height=30   style='z-index:32111;;    p  osition: absolute; top: -75; left: 370;'/>";
 echo '</a>';
  echo "</div >";

  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'No images found for this player.<br />';
  }


  ?>
```

i dont know why ?
is it  because of z-index?
any help appreciated..

Comment: The php isn't much good to us. We need to see the HTML and CSS. Your site link seems to be just hanging and not loading.

Comment: I don't know if this is the origin, but `p  osition: absolute;` will definitively not work (remove space(s))

Comment: @samsamX which line no.?i didnt find  p osition: absolute;??

Comment: A few lines before the `catch ` statement : `echo "<img src=\"" . $path1...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the z-index of the "learn more" link ?

Give the div containing the slide show less z-index and give the link "learn more" greater z-index value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` on both elements. Then you can adjust level with `z-index` (CSS)